# I'm having trouble replacing an empty element in a dictionary in python 3.7

Tags: python, dictionary, object, input

I am trying to find a way to replace an empty object in python but it never worked out

here is the code i tried

```
import datetime
import time

A = {'name : '', ' 'age': 0, 'tasks done': '', 'number of tasks done': 0}
name = ''
age = ''
tasksdone = ''
no_of_tasks_done = 0
print("hello 'Worker'")
time.sleep(2)
name = input("enter name")
age = input("enter age")
tasksdone = input("enter all names given to the tasks you've completed so far")
no_of_tasks_done = input("enter the number of tasks done")

x = datetime.datetime.now()
print(x)
A['name'] : A[name]
A['a'] = A[age]
```

ignore datetime for now
its not yet finished because i need to solve this problem
the user is supposed to make an input into the console and its supposed to put it in the object list
i dont know why it failed
please help me

Comment: I suggest you start by printing *A*. It's almost certainly not what you want

Answer (score 0):

it has to be:

```
name = input("enter name")
age = input("enter age")
A['name'] = name
A['age'] = age
print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the values of the dictionary, you need to use the key and assign the new value to it and also you should convert the `no_of_tasks_done` variable to an integer using the int() function because the user input will be a string.
This is the version of your code that should work as you want:

```
import datetime
import time

A = {'name': '', 'age': 0, 'tasks done': '', 'number of tasks done': 0}
name = ''
age = ''
tasksdone = ''
no_of_tasks_done = 0

print("hello 'Worker'")
time.sleep(2)

name = input("enter name: ")
age = input("enter age: ")
tasksdone = input("enter all names given to the tasks you've completed so far: ")
no_of_tasks_done = int(input("enter the number of tasks done: "))

x = datetime.datetime.now()
print(x)

A['name'] = name
A['age'] = age
A['tasks done'] = tasksdone
A['number of tasks done'] = no_of_tasks_done

print(A)
```

Comment: Age should also be converted to a `int`. There is no error checking so if user enters such as TWO for number of tasks done then the code will fail with an error message. OP should note that this code forms only a single dictionary and a different structure (eg List of Dictionaries) should be used if the intention is to have multiple sets of entries.

Comment: Thank you for pointing those things out and also making it more clear for OP!

Answer (score 0):

If you use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension) with [formatted strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/), you can loop through the [keys](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to build `A` directly without even initiating it with empty values.<sup>([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYLXy.png))</sup>

```py
# keys_A = [*A] ## if you already have A from a previous block
keys_A = ['name', 'age', 'tasks done', 'number of tasks done']

# print("hello 'Worker'")
# time.sleep(2)

A = {k:input(f'enter {k}') for k in keys_A}
```

---

---

If you want values of specific types, you can use a [`try...except...else`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/try-except-else-and-finally-in-python/) to convert the input and [`isinstance`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/isinstance) to check against the type.<sup>([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di93k.png))</sup>

```py
# ref_A = {k:type(v) for k,v in A.items()} ## if you already have A from a previous block
ref_A = {'name': str, 'age': int, 'tasks done': str, 'number of tasks done': int}

# print("hello 'Worker'")
# time.sleep(2)

A = {} ## [ not necessary if you already have A ]
for k, t in ref_A.items():
    while not isinstance((inp:=input(f'enter {k}: ')), t):
        try: inp = t(inp)
        except ValueError as ve: print('! Invalid Input -', ve, '!')
        else: break
    A[k] = inp
```

<sup>[The [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/#walrus-operator-fundamentals) (`:=`) conveniently eliminates that extra line for initiating a variable that will only be used conditionally.]</sup>

---

You can also put the `try...except` in a [function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function) so that you don't need you can go back to using a dict comprehension instead of a [`for`-loop](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/for-loop).<sup>([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3r7r.png))</sup>

```py
def validated_input(promptStr:str, inp_type:type=str):
    while not isinstance((inp:=input(promptStr)), inp_type):
        try: return inp_type(inp)
        except ValueError as ve: print('! Invalid Input -', ve, '!')
    return inp
```

```py
A = {k: validated_input(f'enter {k}: ', t) for k, t in ref_A.items()}

## if you already have A and you just want to update the keys in ref_A:
# for k, t in ref_A.items(): A[k] = validated_input(f'enter {k}: ', t) ## OR
# A = {**A, **{k: validated_input(f'enter {k}: ', t) for k, t in ref_A.items()}}
```

---

You can also write a function to take in a list of inputs

```py
def list_input(itemName:str):
    inps = [] 
    promptStr = f'Enter a {itemName} to add [Or just press ENTER to stop]: ' 
    while (inp:=input(promptStr)).strip(): inps.append(inp)
    return inps
```

and then alter `validated_input` to utilize it [conditionally ofc]

```py
def validated_input(promptStr:str, inp_type:type=str):
    if inp_type in [list, tuple, set]:
        return inp_type(list_input(promptStr))
    while not isinstance((inp:=input(promptStr)), inp_type):
        try: return inp_type(inp)
        except ValueError as ve: print('! Invalid Input -', ve, '!')
    return inp
```

and then you could have `tasks done` as a list and calculate its length for `number of tasks done`.<sup>([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlbtR.png))</sup>

```py
A =  {'name': input('enter name: ')} ## A['name']=input('enter name: ') # if A exists
A['age'] = validated_input('enter age: ', int)
A['tasks done'] = list_input('"task done"') # validated_input('"task done"', list)
A['number of tasks done'] = len(A['tasks done'])
```